# Combobox not displaying value in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

here i m going to bind combobox through datatable in wpf but combobox not displaying value in fornt end can any one tell what the wrong with this.here is code also

```
//XAML
<ComboBox Canvas.Left="148" Canvas.Top="62" Height="23" 
          Name="cmbGameProfile" Width="217" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PROFILE_NAME}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="PROFILE_NAME"  />     

//Code-behind
public static void GameProfileList(ComboBox ddlCategoryType)
{
    try
    {
            DataTable dtGameProfileList = null;   
            try
            {
                ClsDataLayer objDataLayer = new ClsDataLayer();
                objDataLayer.AddParameter("@REF_USER_ID",0);
                dtGameProfileList = objDataLayer.ExecuteDataTable("COMNODE_PROC_GetGameProfile");
                if (dtGameProfileList != null && dtGameProfileList.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    ddlCategoryType.DataContext = dtGameProfileList;
                    ddlCategoryType.DisplayMemberPath = dtGameProfileList.Rows[0]["PROFILE_NAME"].ToString();
                    ddlCategoryType.SelectedValuePath = dtGameProfileList.Rows[0]["PROFILE_ID"].ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }                                  
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well `PROFILE_NAME` is just a column in your results. At the moment `ItemsSource` is bound property `PROFILE_NAME` when it needs to be set to some `IEnumerable`. You need to set it to some view of your `DataTable` so do

```
ddlCategoryType.ItemsSource = dtGameProfileList.DefaultView;
```

or

```
ddlCategoryType.ItemsSource = new DataView(dtGameProfileList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using an ObservableCollection given that WPF will attempt to create your binding before the rendering occurs.

In your xaml you would update the ItemsSource to ItemsSource="{Binding YourClassInstanceMember}" and then in GameProfileList(..) you would convert your non-observable collection class to an ObservableCollection and assign it to your backing field (which would subsequently notify the UI to update).

Some recommended reading

[DataBinding overview] [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[INotifyPropertyChanged]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged

In pseudo code..

```
<Window xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:YourProject.YourViewModelNamespace">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:YourViewViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding GameProfileListItems}"/>
</Window>

public class YourViewViewModel : ViewModelBase (this is something that implements INotifyPropertyChanged)
{
    ObservableCollection<string> _gameProfileListItems;
    ObservableCollection<string> GameProfileListItems
    {
        get { return _gameProfileListItems; }
        set { _gameProfileListItems = value; OnPropertyChanged("GameProfileListItems"); }
    }

    public void SetGameProfileListItems()
    {
        //    go and get your data here, transfer it to an observable collection
        //    and then assign it to this.GameProfileListItems (i would recommend writing a .ToObservableCollection() extension method for IEnumerable)
        this.GameProfileListItems = SomeManagerOrUtil.GetYourData().ToObservableCollection();
    }
}

public class YourView : Window
{
    public void YourView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        InitializeViewModel();
    }

    YourViewViewModel ViewModel
    {
        { get return this.DataContext as YourViewViewModel; }
    }

    void InitializeViewModel()
    {
        this.ViewModel.SetGameProfileListItems();
    }
}
```